# How to disable android run-time location permission prompt in android Unity app

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions

Our Unity app does not use any kind of location services however it gets deployed in the AndroidManifest.xml. As our target sdk version is set to 23, it asks for permissions at runtime which we don't want specifically the location GPS permission since we don't use it but I believe Unity adds because maybe some 3rd party library that we use might be referencing it but I am not sure why it gets added to the manifest xml. Tried to comment the below line of code from manifest but that doesn't work and it still throws a run-time permission prompt

```
>  <!-- <uses-permission
> android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" /> -->
```

If I set the target sdk to 22 (to switch back to the old permission model at install time) it throws build errors as it says android sdk tools is current using sdk version 23.

I know we can revoke the permissions from the settings menu but that does not solve our problem

Is there a way to revoke the ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION or ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION permission prompt at run-time in any way during build time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**SDK version 23** = **Android M**. Android M checks for permission during **run-time** instead of **install time**. The only way I know to get ride of this is to get **access** to the **source code** and comment/remove any code that gets location of the device.

First, find out **which** plugin is asking for the permission by **removing** all plugins in your project and bringing them back, one by one. If you find the plugin with the location problem, ask the provider of the plugin for the **source code**.

If you **can't** get the source code, you can **decompile** the jar or aar file and **remove** the part of the code that contains Location/GPS code, then **recompile** it back to jar or aar file.